# How to generate and then redirect to that generated link in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have some troubles. Here is my code:

```
get '/generate' do
  @link = Link.create(url: Helpers.random, message: "my new ffffff")
  session[:test] = @link.url
  redirect ("/message/#{session[:test]}")
end

get "/message/#{session[:test]}" do
  erb :buttons
end
```

In first method I generate some link, and in second I want to redirect to that generated link. How could I do it easy? Because I receive

> Sinatra doesn’t know this ditty.

Even if I take away **session[:test] = @link.url** from get method  to separate method I receive:

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `session' for
>   main:Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 "scopes" here and you're mixing them in a way that's not possible.

```
get "/message/#{session[:test]}" do
```

^^ this is run *when the app starts up*, it is *never* re-run. The content *inside* the block could be run multiple times, but not the route matcher.

The way to handle this is to change the route matcher to accept a URL param:

```
get "/message/:some_var"
```

Then in the block refer to `params[:some_var]`.

Comment: in 'get /generate method' I changed params[:local] = @link.url, then in 'get "/message/:local' after redirect I don't receive generated link, just http://127.0.0.1:9393/message/:local

Comment: @JessieScinor no, keep the `get '/generate'` method the same as in your original question. Only change `get "/message/#{session[:test]}"` to `get "/message/:some_var"`. The `:some_var` thing is a special type of var that _only_ works in route definitions. Please read up on the Routes section here: http://sinatrarb.com/intro.html

Comment: but it won't solve my problem.. after redirect I need link something like that '/message/kh4sfhrs3'

Comment: @JessieScinor yes. `redirect "/message/#{session[:test]}"` will make the url `'/message/kh4sfhrs3'` as you want. Then the route handler _extracts_ the id with `get "/message/:some_id"`. You can read the value from that `:some_id` variable with `params[:some_id]` (the variable can be called whatever you want)

Comment: So strange that it worked somehow until I cleared cookies..now it fails

Comment: And that is failing still... I tried many times to restart server and etc and it always shows 'Sinatra doesn’t know this ditty.'

Comment: You should only redirect if `@link` creates succesfully (has no errors) and if `@link.url` is not empty. Otherwise you're redirecting to `/message/` which is not matched (there is no value for `:some_var`)

Comment: If `session[:test]` is empty then you're just redirecting to `/message/` and there's no route matcher for that